# IValueConverter and Localization

Tags: wpf, xaml, localization, ivalueconverter

I am currently using an IValueConverter to convert Boolean Values to Yes/No text to display in the RadGridView.

```
Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As System.Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.Convert
            Return If(CBool(value), "Yes", "No")
        End Function
```

As you can see, this is my current implementation, and I was wondering how can I use localization to it and display Yes/No in other languages?

Can someone kindly help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to implement localization in the WPF UI.

Either using Microsoft's [Localisation Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718.aspx)

or with Resource file methods. There are quite a few implementations of this that makes localization way easier than the Microsoft's method which has some overhead like giving Uid's to all elements to be localized and sorts.

One such plugin giving a resource file localization is [Infralution WPF Localization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35159/WPF-Localization-Using-RESX-Files)

This seems to work well(author active in replying to bugs in code-project, updates are prompt and **MVVM** friendly). It's attached example demonstrates a similar example to yours where the author shows how binding a value in the view can be localized at run-time based on a set of target values it can accept.

I'd suggest you read through the code-project article, Mess about with the accompanying example and you should have a much better idea of how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the IValueConverter altogether and use triggers this way you are able to localize the text normally here is an example for achieving this with textbox:

```
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding i}" Value="True">
                     <Setter Property="Text" Value="Yes"/>
                 </DataTrigger>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding i}" Value="False">
                     <Setter Property="Text" Value="No"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
```

assuming i is the bool you are binding to.

Comment: My scenario is a little bit different here. @Mhashim: the sample provided is great but is not applicable in my case

Answer (score 0):

You can use .resx files as dictionares

[image: App.resx]

The default language is inside App.resx and other laguages have appendix e.g. .pl

To use localized string you call Resources

```
Resources.App.Common_Yes
```

The example of BooleanToLocalizedStringConverter

```
internal class BooleanToLocalizedStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string result = "Class BooleanToLocalizedString function Convert Error";
        if (value is bool)
        {
            result = ((bool)value) ? Resources.App.Common_Yes : Resources.App.Common_No;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

There is an example how to use IValueConverter
https://wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/